# Percentile in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, percentile

Good morning the community,

I am trying to code a macro in which I start from a an array in one tab, and in another tab, I write percentile computations (70%).
In the picture attached, left side is my database, and right side is the result I would like to get:

[image]

I am stuck with the function itself and how to seperate each name.

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
 Sub Maths()
Dim Result As Double
Dim Apm As Worksheet
Set Apm = Worksheets("SOURCE")
Dim Bilan As Worksheet
Set Bilan = Worksheets("bilan")

Range("B2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Data = Selection.Value

'Clear worksheet Yield
For i = 3 To 10
    For j = 1 To 5
            Bilan.Cells(i, j).ClearContents
    Next j
Next i


            ' I use (1) and (2) below to test the copy/paste
            Bilan.Columns(1).Rows(2).Value = Apm.Columns.Rows(3).Value
            Bilan.Columns(2).Rows(2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile_Inc (Data, 0.68)

MsgBox ("Work done")
Bilan.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: What is this line: `Data = Apm.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value` supposed to do? As of now, it won't do anything, or to be more precise, anything meaningful

Comment: Hi, it was a typo. And yes the program is not able to do anything because I have no clue I to use the percentiel... :/

Comment: You might like to start here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/percentile-inc-function-680f9539-45eb-410b-9a5e-c1355e5fe2ed

Comment: can you elaborate how to calculate the figures on the right?

Comment: Where you type `Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile_Inc`, what are the arguments when you call that function?

Comment: For the figures on the right, Adrien = 53.76 = percentile of (36 96 52 48) with k=0.7. Actually i believe that data have to be sorted first (either within the code or manually before starting the program). regarding the argument of Application.WorksheetFunction.Percentile_Inc, I do not kow which arguments to take, I am a newbie on VBA and I don't understand how I can use this function :/

Comment: I just update my code where i can compute the percentile (for the whole table, one column) and paste them in the new tab, however I like to compute each percentile depending on the name